# Why in this simple math problem in c++ the result is different depending on the place of the float? I want to know the logic behind it

Tags: c++, math

```
#include <iostream>; 

using namespace std; 

 /* this one works out when the float of the pi & area are in the end, but when it's in the top it does not work? */

int main() 
{ 

float a, b; 

/* float pi = 3.14 ;

float area = (pi*b*b/4) * ((2*a-b) / (2*a+b));  if it's  in here it doesn't work */

cout << "please inter  number \n"; 
cin >> a ;

cout << "please inter  number \n"; 
cin >> b ;

cout << "****\n" ;

float pi = 3.14 ;

float area = (pi*b*b/4) * ((2*a-b) / (2*a+b));

cout << area << endl; 

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can't calculate the area until after you get the input from the user.

Comment: C++ is not Excel. When you say `float area = (pi * b * b/4) * ...;`, it uses the current values of `pi`, `b`, and `a`. If those values change in the future, it doesn't go back and update `area`. If those values are uninitialized, it's undefined behavior to use them.

Comment: Thanks Nathan Pierson.

Comment: Also, only use float when you really need to conserve memory - prefer to use double.

Comment: If you need to define the relationship early, and calculate it later, you could use `auto area = [&]{ return (pi*b*b/4) * ((2*a-b) / (2*a+b)); };` early, and then later after getting the values of `a` and `b` do the `cout << area() << endl;` (note the **parens** to invoke the lambda).

Comment: @Eljay, I'm not convinced that's a good idea. It ties the calculation to very specific `a` and `b` variables (and `pi` but that's probably unlikely to change). It would probably be better to have a function that you passed `a` and `b` into so you could use arbitrary variables for the calculation), or at least a lambda that could do the same.

Comment: @paxdiablo • I agree, but I was just trying to show the OP how one could do what was trying to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area gets set depending on the values *currently* in the variables used in the expression.

With the expression at the top, neither `a` nor `b` have been set to your input values. Instead they will have some arbitrary value, meaning your area will also have some arbitrary value. With the expression *after* the input of `a` and `b`, those values will be the actual values you entered.

You can see this clearer if you place the following code immediately after the calculation (in both situations):

```c
std::cout << "DEBUG: a = " << a << ", b = " << b
    << ", pi = " << pi << ", area = " << area << '\n';
```